# convert a string to datetime in LinqToEntities (inside the query)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a date in the string format in a table and I need to compare it with the parameter to retrieve all rows that match with the given date. how can I do this? I can't use DateTime.Parse and Convert.ToDateTime. both of them are not supported (I get an error). Is this possible at all in Linq OR do I have to write a stored procedure for it due to this limitation?

Note: I can't change the datatype of the column from varchar to DateTime, because that column contains other values as well, not just dates. it is a generic table and the column may contain different types of values based on the values in other columns. changing this design is outside the scope of this question.

sample code ("x" is the date parameter passed into this method):

```
    from t1 in Table1
    where EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Parse(t1.Value),x) == 0
    select new {t1.Col1, t1.Col2};
```

Update: if I use DateTime.Parse, I get the error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." similar error for Convert.ToDateTime as well.

Comment: If the date is in string format, couldn’t you apply a `ToString` on your `DateTime` (presumably `x`) and then do a string comparison?

Comment: but that isn't the right way to compare dates, right?

Comment: Ideally, no, but if your dates are already in string format, then you won’t lose much. You will, however, need to handle issues such as date-time format discrepancies (dd/MM/yyyy vs MM/dd/yyyy) and timezone offsets yourself, if present in your data.

Comment: Can you change the database field to a date? Why store dates as strings?

Comment: What is the error you are getting from DateTime.Parse? I would go down that route first before trying to come up with another solution.

Comment: Please see the error message above.

Comment: @frenchie, I explained the reason for the data type in my post (column may contain other values as well, not just dates). whether it is a good design or not, that is another question.

Comment: How about creating a view on your table, with a computed column which casts your varchar column to a datetime if it pattern-matches as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Replicating my comment to paste some sample code)*

If the date is in string format, couldn’t you apply a `ToString` on your `DateTime` (presumably `x`) and then do a string comparison?

Since you are working on string representations, you need to take care of several issues that would otherwise be handled transparently by `DateTime`, including:

- Date-time format discrepancies (`dd/MM/yyyy` vs `MM/dd/yyyy`).
- Presence or absence of leading zeros for single-digit days and months (e.g. `01/01/2011` vs `1/1/2001`).
- Two-digit or four-digit representation of years (e.g. `01/01/2011` vs `01/01/11`).
- Timezone offsets. For example, the date for `2011-01-01 23:30 -01:00` would actually be `2011-01-02`.

The sample code below will work if all your dates are in US format, with two-digit days and months, four-digit years, and no timezone offsets.

```
from t1 in Table1
where t1.Value.StartsWith(x.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy"))
select new {t1.Col1, t1.Col2};
```

**Edit**: Alternate solution:

If you can define a view in your database, you can circumvent the problem by casting your `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME` selectively. I’m assuming that `Value` is the name of your date column.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, Value, 101) AS Value, Col1, Col2
FROM Table1
WHERE ISDATE(Value) = 1
```

Then, in your LINQ, do a simple `DateTime` equality check:

```
from t1 in Table1
where t1.Value == x.Date
select new {t1.Col1, t1.Col2};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I haven't tried the view option yet, but I guess it should work if EF supports views. but creating a view to just get around this problem doesn't look like a proper solution for me. not sure why EF doesn't support such a basic requirement of casting string to dates

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the issues that @Douglas points about work with string representations, you can convert a `string` to `DateTime` in *Linq to Entities* using `SqlFunctions` and `DbFunctions` classes:

```
DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(SqlFunctions.DatePart("yy", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("ss", dateString));
```

Comment: Good answer. I wish there was a way to encapsulate it in an extension function.

Answer (score 1):

This works. You need an Extensionmethod to make the dateTime parsing safe. After that you can use the result of that method in the Linq query. It will fetch all rows from the table so performance wise this might be a less optimal (!) solution. It answers the question though.

```
    void Main()
    {
         var stringDates = new List<string> { "2011-13-01", "2011-01-12" };

         DateTime paramDate = new DateTime(2011,01,13);

         var q = from stringDate in stringDates
            let realdate = stringDate.SafeParse()
            where realdate == paramDate
            select new { stringDate, realdate };

         q.Dump();
    }


    static class StringDateParseExt
    {
       public static DateTime SafeParse(this string  any)
        {
          DateTime parsedDate;
          DateTime.TryParseExact(any, 
                "yyyy-dd-MM", 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , 
                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                out parsedDate);
          return parsedDate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: LinqToSql doesn't seem to support any DateTime functions which includes Parse, TryParse etc. even if I use extension methods, it still calls the same functions inside the method. This one is not hitting database, that could be the reason it is working for you

Answer (score 0):

Linq to SQL does have support for Convert.ToDateTime to go from String to DateTime. I'm not sure about Entity Framework though, if you are really using that instead.  There is also a class SqlMethods with a DateDiff method that you can use to get translated to TSQL's DateDiff function.

Linq to SQL will also let you convert between types by casting. You can't directly cast between String and DateTime, but you can cheat by casting to Object first and then to DateTime. The Object cast gets erased in the translate but the DateTime cast get converted to a TSQL convert operation.

Comment: I tried by casting to object and then to DateTime. still getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried casting?

```
Expression<Func<string, DateTime>> expr = s => (DateTime)(object)s;
```

---

Further web searching reveals that the lack of string-date conversion is a missing feature in EF.  It looks like some string conversions are supported, but not date parsing:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx

Comment: Is there an implicit conversion from `String` to `DateTime`?

Comment: I didn't see such a conversation yet but if exists again you will get similar error in runtime.

Comment: @Douglas, yes I suppose it would help if the compiler would accept my code.  Fixed.